# Powershell foreach and if statement

Tags: powershell, if-statement, foreach

I am trying to check against the credential manager for any "Domain" entry, If "Domain" entry **DOESN"T** exist then a pop up window will appear for  user to  enter username and password. If it exist then simply stop script.

This PowerShell script is suppose to run at windows login in order to add domain credentials if they don't exist in the Windows Credential Manager, and then maps a network drive. If the script detects no domain credentials added in the Windows Credential Manager - then it will prompt the user to enter it.

I am confused at where i am wrong in my logic, when the code runs it ignores the IF statement and carries on popping the window for username & password even if there is a domain user in the Windows Credential Manager and runs the cmdkey /add and net use command.

I am deploying this script using Intune, and i have tested it without the IF statement and it works fine. I am trying to make the IF statement work first before testing it again.

This is my code:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") 
$error.clear()


try { 


cmdkey /list | foreach {
if($_ -match 'Domain')
    {
        [PSCustomObject]@{Account = $matches.1}
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Already exist!")
        
    }

    

else {

    
# Captures username
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------


Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$form.Text = "Enter Username"
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200) 
$form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(75,120)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = "OK"
$OKButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$form.AcceptButton = $OKButton
$form.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150,120)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
$CancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
$form.CancelButton = $CancelButton
$form.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,20) 
$label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
$label.Text = "Enter Username: "
$form.Controls.Add($label) 

$textBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$textBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40) 
$textBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) 
$form.Controls.Add($textBox) 

$form.Topmost = $True

$form.Add_Shown({$textBox.Select()})
$result = $form.ShowDialog()

if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
{
    $x = $textBox.Text
    $x
}




# Captures password
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$form.Text = "Enter Password"
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200) 
$form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(75,120)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = "OK"
$OKButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$form.AcceptButton = $OKButton
$form.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150,120)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
$CancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
$form.CancelButton = $CancelButton
$form.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,20) 
$label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
$label.Text = "Enter Password: "
$form.Controls.Add($label) 

$textBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$textBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40) 
$textBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) 
$form.Controls.Add($textBox) 

$form.Topmost = $True

$form.Add_Shown({$textBox.Select()})
$result = $form.ShowDialog()

if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
{
    $x2 = $textBox.Text
    $x2
}

 cmdkey.exe /add:ae7msd-dc /user:$x /pass:$x2
 net use U: "\\SERVER\FOLDER" /persistent:yes
 break

}

}
}




catch { [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Not Working!") }
if (!$error) {
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("IT'S DONE!")
}
```

This is the output i get on the Powershell editor when there is no DOMAIN user added to the Windows Credential Manager:

```
PS C:\Users\hadi> C:\temp\add-cred.ps1

GAC    Version        Location                                                                                                                      
---    -------        --------                                                                                                                      
True   v4.0.30319     C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll       
hmohsen
Abc!2345

CMDKEY: Credential added successfully.
The command completed successfully.

OK
```

This is what i get when running the script even though there is already a domain user added to the windows credential manager:

```
PS C:\Users\hadi> C:\temp\add-cred.ps1

GAC    Version        Location                                                                                                                      
---    -------        --------                                                                                                                      
True   v4.0.30319     C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll       
hmohsen
Abc!2345

CMDKEY: Credential added successfully.
net : System error 85 has occurred.
At C:\temp\add-cred.ps1:124 char:2
+  net use U: "\\SERVER\FOLDER" /persistent:yes
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (System error 85 has occurred.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
The local device name is already in use.
OK
```

My aim is to stop the script the script when there is an entry for a Domain user in the Windows Credential Manager, but the script keeps going anyway.
The logic is flawed, but how can i fix it please!

Comment: You've only described what you _want_ to happen without mentioning what _actually_ happens.  How are you scheduling the script to run at logon?  Does it run at all?  Are there any errors? Can you test with a simpler script that just writes to a file, for example, to prove it ran?

Comment: Thank you @boxdog, i have included the output

Comment: Can you share the script? Otherwise the error does give some pointers if you read it...

Comment: Thank you @alexzelaya here is the ps1 we.tl/t-yxBQEeLuoR

Comment: @HQJ, please post it via your question. Opening an unwanted PS1 is not something we do

Comment: @alexzelaya the whole script is pasted in the question

Comment: A few questions pop into mind. What user context is the script running on? You can use `$env:username` to check this. Also, there might be some kind of issue with your condition, try `-like "*domian*"` instead of the `-match`.

Comment: As @alexzelaya said, there may be an issue with the condition (the if statement is never evaluating to true). It appears `cmdkey /list` returns an array of strings, what string would tell you there is a domain user? `Type: Domain`?.

Comment: @NickKimbrough yes, Type: Domain would tell me that there is a domain user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code lies within this statement:

```
cmdkey /list | foreach {
if($_ -match 'Domain')
```

The `if` statement never evaluates to true because the match is never true.

The `cmdkey /list` command returns an array of formatted strings. The string you want to match would be `Type: Domain` (with whitespace potentially before and after).

Changing your code to the following should result in getting the correct matches:

```
cmdkey /list | ForEach-Object {
    if($_ -like '*Type: Domain*')
    {
        [PSCustomObject]@{Account = $matches.1}
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Already exist!")
    }
```